# Unable to copy item from mapped network drive using powershell as file contains wierd characters

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to copy files from mapped network drive.Some of them gets copied but others are not copied as filename has got some wierd characters.

for example my mapped network drive Z: contains the following files:

1. skifteretsattest 1(1).pdf
2. MailBody.msg
3. k�rekort terje(3).pdf

I am able to copy first two files from mapped network drive but not the last one using the below command

```
Copy-Item  -LiteralPath Z:\$name  -Destination I:\Dat\SomePath\ss/ -Force
```

The error which I get is:

> Copy-Item : Could not find file 'Z:\k�rekort terje(3).pdf

I tried [WildcardPattern]::Escape($name) but that also did not work
Kindly help if anybody knows the solution

Comment: Try This    Copy-Item  -Path Z:\*  -Destination I:\Dat\SomePath\ss\

Comment: @KemalK.  I tried what you told still I get this error: Copy-Item : Could not find file 'Z:\k�rekort terje(3).pdf'.

Comment: `�` is a replacement character. Try `Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\ -Filter "*rekort*"` to see real file name.

Comment: @JosefZ - I tried but I get the same error again.   I can see the source file name ie. AttachmentName=k%ef%bf%bdrekort+terje(3).pdf

Comment: Can you copy the file with `[System.IO.File]::Copy("Z:\$name", "I:\Dat\SomePath\ss\$name")` ?

Comment: `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode('k%ef%bf%bdrekort+terje(3).pdf')` returns `k�rekort terje(3).pdf`. You are talking about `AttachmentName` so [edit] the question and share a [mcve]. How is the attachment saved? This [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case supposedly origins in an incompatibility (or different encoding) between sender and receiver (mail) clients?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use robocopy.exe oder xcopy.exe instead?
Maybe old "dir /x" can help to find out the old "8.3" filename (like "GET-GP~1.PS1" for "Get-GPProcessingTime.ps1") and this can be used to copy or rename the file?
I also remember something about bypassing file system logic using unc-like syntax like \\0\driveletter\directory or whatever - unfortunately I don't remember the exact syntax. Maybe someone else does?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\"
$files | % { Copy-Item -Destination "I:\Dat\SomePath\ss" }
```

Comment: Interesting... I tried it, using that exact same file name and it worked fine. What errors are you getting? What is the output of a DIR command run in the Z: drive?

Comment: It asks for the path like---  Supply values for the following parameters:Path[0]:  I supply the path like Z:\k�rekort terje(3).pdf ......it does'nt copy

Comment: What code are you using? The two lines I provided above will copy everything in Z:\ to the destination folder on I: - you shouldn't need to provide a path other than to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

Comment: I am using windows powershell..and its asks for parameters